# The Star Rating widget with jQuery ajax load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

It works fine when the page first loads into browser

[image: Without problem]

However, problem starts when the the DIV container contains this star rating, was loaded again with Ajax load. It was reset to its original radio button:

[image: with problem]

The code to made this rating star works was just as simple as following:

Star Rating Widget Plugin:

```
$("#stars-wrapper").stars({
  cancelShow: false,
  disabled: true
});

<span id="stars-wrapper">
                <input type="radio" id="rate1" name="newrate" value="1" title="Poor" />
                <input type="radio" id="rate2" name="newrate" value="2" title="Not that bad" />
                <input type="radio" id="rate3" name="newrate" value="3" title="Average" />
                <input type="radio" id="rate4" name="newrate" value="4" title="Good" />
                <input type="radio" id="rate5" name="newrate" value="5" title="Perfect" />
 </span>
```

Ajax Load:

```
$('#content_pane').load( href );
```

Does anyone have idea how to tackle this problem? It seems to be not working well with Ajax load.

Comment: It would be great if you can make a jsFiddle of your code in the future, especially for such simple and self-contained problems. It would be much easier for us to help you and post working solutions.

Comment: It's not convenient to put it in jsFiddle as it involves server side as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that you're currently only binding to elements that already exist on the page. When you load new data into the page using an AJAX request, your stars widget is not live and is thus not bound to these new elements.

You would need to re-bind to these elements within your AJAX load like so:

```
$('#content_pane').load( href, function() {
  $("#stars-wrapper").stars({
    cancelShow: false,
    disabled: true
  });
});
```

Perhaps your widget includes a `live` API, but `live` has since been deprecated in jQuery.

Comment: I've already tried similar way and it's not working. I tried when after posting, I executed the plugin again. However, I did try your this solution also and same results were produced.

Yes, the live() has been deprecated and replaced by on() in jQuery 1.7. Maybe I should try on the live() or on() method also.